# How can I fetch POST data with selenium needed for a download?

Tags: python, selenium, wget

I need to automate a file download - not with selenium but with wget - that requires establishing a web session, executing some simple click commands, and then using POST data to initiate the download.

Using selenium this works rather well up to the point where the file download occurs. The download I don't want to automate with selenium because it's much simpler to do this via wget. But wget needs some download token IDs that the server generates when a directory command is sent via the web interface.

So: with selenium I can start the session on the server, obtain the coookie, and trigger the directory generating command.

With wget, I want to download a large number of files using a token ID that is generated when the first download is triggered (this then remains the same for the entire duration of the session).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fetch the POST data that is sent back to the server when a download link is clicked?

Comment: Where does the application store the token ID that is sent back from server? (cookies, URL, form, js code, ...)

Comment: I would like to say that Selenium cannot retrieve HTTP response data. But Selenium can read data in DOM, cookies, or js code.

Comment: That's the $100 question - I only see that token in the wget command line that the cliget plugin displays when clicking the download link. There's only one cookie being transferred (the CAKEPHP session cookie)

Comment: Ok, I've located where the token is set: It's in the javascript page source. I can get that variable easily using result = driver.execute_script("return TOKEN"

Comment: I would suggest don't wait to download the POST data when the download link is clicked. Download the POST data *instead* of clicking the download button.

Comment: Indeed I found I can just load the token when the page loads. Simple!